# How to create a new column from two different tables when the values (commission) change in different dates, in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am kind of new to POWER BI and I am practicing and trying to find a different solution for possible problems in real life.

I have a SALES table with dates, user, product, category, number_articles, price and my commission.

| Dates | User | prod | category | num_articles | price | my_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 |
| 28/06/2022 | 558 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 |
| 29/06/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 |
| 30/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 |
| 01/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 |
| 02/07/2022 | 558 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 |
| 03/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 |
| 04/07/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 |

I have a CATEGORY table where I have the category, product, commission_1, commission_2

| category | Product | commission_1 | commission_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Single | XRTD | 1 | 1 |
| BOX | MRPD | 1 | 0,80 |
| BOX | RTGM | 1 | 0,80 |

I am adding the commissions to the sales table so I am able to create a Total column, running total, etc and, of course, a revenue measure, as you can see the category table products have commision_1 and some commision_2.

To add the commissions to my sales table I am using LOOKUPVALUES,

Prod_commission = LOOKUPVALUE(
category[commission_2], TABLE_category[Category], Sales_Table[Category] )

And I got the different commissions added for every category product correctly.

The COMPLETE TABLE looks like

| Dates | User | prod | category | num_articles | price | my_commission | Prod_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 | 558 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 29/06/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 30/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 01/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 02/07/2022 | 558 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 03/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 04/07/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 | 0,8 |

The problem I have is that from July, 01/07/2022 the commission_2 - 0,8 is not valid anymore, so basically, all products have the same commission from July 2022 which is commision_1.

How I can do LOOKUPVALUE (or what can I use?) to place both commissions until 30/06/2022 but from 01/07/2022 everything is just commission_1 ?

I need that the commission from the category products is 1 and 0,8 until 06/30/2022 and 1 from 01/07/2022, and looks like:

| Dates | User | prod | category | num_articles | price | my_commission | Prod_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 28/06/2022 | 558 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 29/06/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 | 0,8 |
| 30/06/2022 | 458 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 01/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 02/07/2022 | 558 | XRTD | single | 1 | 0,8 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 03/07/2022 | 458 | MRPD | BOX | 1 | 10 | 0,05 | 1 |
| 04/07/2022 | 589 | RTGM | BOX | 1 | 20 | 0,05 | 1 |

Is there a solution to this?

I have tried with IF and DATEBETWEEN but does not work, please can somebody enlight me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This feels like data shaping to me and belongs in PQ. Are you open to a PQ solution?

Comment: I am always open to learning something new David so I am happy to check your answer, thanks!

Comment: Whats the theory of how the  commission column names in CATEGORY table map to months in the SALES table?  Its obvious for a single limited case, but there needs to be a method

Answer (score 1):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjLXNzDTNzIwMlJQ0lEyMbUAURFBIS5AqjgzLz0nFSRgCCIMdCwglIGpUqwOUKsFslZTiFbfoACQVif/CLg+QwNUbZYo2iwsQVRQiLsvmjYjVG3GBmQ71MBQ38AcXSthhxoYIWszJclGY/JsNEGxkaigiQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Dates = _t, User = _t, prod = _t, category = _t, num_articles = _t, price = _t, my_commission = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type date}, {"User", Int64.Type}, {"prod", type text}, {"category", type text}, {"num_articles", Int64.Type}, {"price", Int64.Type}, {"my_commission", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", (x)=> Table.SelectRows( Category, each x[prod] = [Product] )),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each if [Dates] <= #date(2022,6,30) then [Custom][commission_1]{0} else [Custom][commission_2]{0}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: That works for one set of dates but  I was expecting this is a small sample and there would be lots more dates and columns related to those

Comment: Yes agreed. I just took the problem at face value as I was in a rush but you're right that this won't scale if there are more dates. Let's see what OP says and whether it needs to be more flexible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The new column I added does change based on date as your problem stated. If you have more data, please post it or answer horsey's question for something more generalised

Comment: Bad enough I'm a horseyride, now I have a diminutive?

Comment: David that is that table that I have already done, meaning I can get directly that table from my model creating a new column with LOOKUPVALUE. 

A little more CONTEXT I have around 8 years data in the CATEGORY table some products have commission_1 and some others commission_2 BUT from JULY 2022 ALL products have commission_1, so I need to make the past calculations with both commissions and future with the new standard commission.

Comment: I think my problem is that I can not think in a solutions to make this happened in the same column, for example I was trying to use IF and LOOKUPVALUES separating by dates: 

"Prod_commission = 
       IF ( sales[Date] <= 30/60/2022, 
       
        LOOKUPVALUE(
            category[commission_2], 
            category[Category], 
            Sales[Category]
        ),
        IF ( sales[Date] >= 01/07/2022, 
            LOOKUPVALUE(
                category[commission_1], 
                category[Category], 
                sales[Category] 
             )
        )
    )"

Comment: But is not working for some reason is giving me commission_1 to all the years and not just from JULY.

Hope this provide more context. 

Thanks

Comment: Apologies @horseyride - I'll make sure to use your full and proper title going forward ;).

Comment: @fachc, that is exactly what the code I have provided does. It provides commission_1 if date <= 30/06/22 and commission_2 after that. I must be missing something so I will leave to others to see if they can figure it out.